# I need to copy a component from angular and change it as another component

Tags: node.js, angular, frontend, backend

I made a blog using mongoose angular and nodejs
I made the admin part of it
admin can add or delete or edit blogs
I need to create another component named as "view" to show the blogs for the users
I created an auth for admin and he can also see the blogs which he added
I want to copy that component and make another named as "view" and also want to remove the auth

Answer (score 0):

No need to copy component you can simply , create new router to navigate view mode with using same view component without auth